# how to fix Error: export 'ɵsupportsWebAnimations'

Tags: angular

im trying to replicate this component:

stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-star-rating?file=package.json

however, on my project im unable to run it due to the following errors:

```
./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/animations.mjs:533:9-31 - Error: export 'ɵsupportsWebAnimations' (imported as 'ɵsupportsWebAnimations') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser' (possible exports: AnimationDriver, ɵAnimation, ɵAnimationEngine, ɵAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵNoopAnimationDriver, ɵNoopAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵWebAnimationsDriver, ɵWebAnimationsPlayer, ɵWebAnimationsStyleNormalizer, ɵallowPreviousPlayerStylesMerge, ɵcontainsElement, ɵinvokeQuery, ɵvalidateStyleProperty)

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/animations.mjs:533:69-88 - Error: export 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver' (imported as 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser' (possible exports: AnimationDriver, ɵAnimation, ɵAnimationEngine, ɵAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵNoopAnimationDriver, ɵNoopAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵWebAnimationsDriver, ɵWebAnimationsPlayer, ɵWebAnimationsStyleNormalizer, ɵallowPreviousPlayerStylesMerge, ɵcontainsElement, ɵinvokeQuery, ɵvalidateStyleProperty)
```

i have already did the

```
npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk @angular/animations --force
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already had a `package.json` file in your project all you needed to do is run:

1. `npm i` to install all the declared dependencies on the project
2. `npm run serve` to serve your Angular application.

I can also see that project is quite old (Angular 5, we're currently on Angular 13) so perhaps you'll need to migrate some code to the current version you're using

Answer (score 1):

I changed @angular/animations version and I solved this problem.

on package.json,

```
"@angular/animations": "13.0.1",
"@angular/cdk": "13.0.1",
"@angular/common": "13.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "13.0.1",
"@angular/core": "13.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "13.0.1",
"@angular/language-service": "13.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "13.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "13.0.1",
"@angular/router": "13.0.1",
```

When @angular/animations version is 13.2.3 (latest), same problem has occurred.
Fix your version same with angular version.